# Loading X509 Certificate: Error in Azure, can't reproduce locally

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, x509certificate

I have code to load an X509 certificate from my appsettings.json file along with the password (a base64 encoded pfx file), that looks like this:

```
    public static X509Certificate2 LoadSsoCertificate(IConfiguration config)
    {
        //this should be a self-signed PFX certificate with the private key included.
        var certificateText = config["SSO:x509Certificate"];
        //this should be the password to open/ read the certificate.
        var certificatePassword = config["SSO:SecretKeyPassphrase"];

        var certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateText);
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, certificatePassword);
        return cert;
    }
```

This works fine when testing locally, but when I deployed to an Azure app service, I got this mystifying exception:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(Byte[] rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.SingleSignOn.LoadSsoCertificate(IConfiguration config) in d:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\SingleSignOn.cs:line 43
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.Configure(Saml2Options options) in d:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.cs:line 51
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.Configure(String name, Saml2Options options) in d:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.cs:line 78
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<InitializeAsync>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at MyCompany.SoaToolkit.LoggingContext.AspNetCore.Middleware.Configuration.<>c.<<UseLoggingContextRequests>b__0_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

It says the specified "network" password is incorrect, but it's the same password that works locally, so I can't imagine the problem is actually the password, and it shouldn't be trying to use a "network" either.  Can anyone shed some light on what the problem is, here, and offer suggestions on how to make this relatively simple code work?

**UPDATE**

Based upon @Crypt32's comments, I created a new certificate directly in Azure and saved it as a PFX to my local desktop, then Base64-encoded it and shoehorned it into my appsettings file.  Again, this worked fine locally, but when I deployed to Azure, I got a similar but also similarly mystifying exception:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.Import(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.SingleSignOn.LoadSsoCertificate(IConfiguration config) in D:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\SingleSignOn.cs:line 40
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.Configure(Saml2Options options) in D:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.cs:line 51
   at MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core.Configuration.ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.Configure(String name, Saml2Options options) in D:\a\1\s\MyCompany.AuthenticationServices.Core\Configuration\ConfigureMultiTenantSaml2Options.cs:line 78
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<InitializeAsync>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at MyCompany.SoaToolkit.LoggingContext.AspNetCore.Middleware.Configuration.<>c.<<UseLoggingContextRequests>b__0_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, can you try with the following call to the constructor?
new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
The X509Certificate2 constructor is maybe trying to access the private key store of the local user. Even if you provide a pfx containing the private key.

Comment: I wouldn't think I'd have access to the MachineKey stuff, but I can try...

Comment: @Anouar I tried and there was no change to the error message.

Comment: The problem is either, with PFX file (local and remote PFX files are protected with different passwords), or the password used in constructor call. I would debug the code on server and check if: PFX is the right one, password is correct and this password can open PFX locally. There is a chance that PFX is protected with algorithm which is not supported by Azure.

Comment: @Crypt32 it's exactly the same pfx and password; I literally deployed the same appsettings file that I'm using locally, with no transformations whatsoever.  I also don't see how Azure would _need_ to support the protection algorithm; shouldn't that be handled in the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates library?  Though the call to Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore() is suspicious...

Comment: `shouldn't that be handled in the <...>`. .NET Crypto is just a wrapper over native CryptoAPI functions. Windows 10 has introduced new PFX export (availavle in MMC only) capabilities which may not be compatible with previous systems or other platforms. I would try to re-create the PFX using compatible settings and try again.

Comment: @Crypt32 Pls see my update... If I create the self-signed cert in Azure, it should be compatible, right?  I do get a different error, but it's just as mystifying since I'm not using a file...

Comment: Yes, if you create the PFX in Azure directly, it should be compatible. Where is updated code? Stack trace shows different code path.

Comment: @Crypt32 Yeah I just created the cert with the constructor instead of using the collection.  I did figure it out, you were very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, @Crypt32 got me on the right path here, but it's not obvious.

1) The problem had nothing to do with the password.  It had to do with the fact that I made the self-signed certificate using openssl with algorithms that Windows 10 apparently supports... but Azure doesn't.  I created a new certificate on Azure and that worked fine.

2) I also had a problem with the keystore (this was the error about not finding the file), for reasons I do not understand.  It seems Azure can't figure out how to create a service account keystore for an app service and that blows my mind.  I switched to a blob-based keystore (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.azuredataprotectionbuilderextensions.persistkeystoazureblobstorage?view=aspnetcore-3.0)) and all of a sudden things seem to be running again... or at least, not failing to start.

Moral of the story: X509 error messages are worse than worthless.  Would it kill MS to make an error message that actually described the problem?  Hopefully this answer will help someone else out.

Comment: I am having the same problem and will try to use an Azure certificate to see if that solves the problem. However, is that not restrictive for Azure to only be able to use certificates that was generated by Azure? Certificate can be generated in many places....

Comment: it has to do with the encryption and hashing algorithms they support, as I recall.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyHolovacs. I had similar problem. When I created pfx file under Win10 with openssl, Azure did not like the certificates, complained about password being wrong when it was not. I created the certifacates in MacOs with same openssl commands, and it was all good.