# Azure WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct when publishing despite correct password

Tags: .net, azure, security, cryptography, pfx

I'm loading an x509 certificate from a pfx on the filesystem

```
new X509Certificate2(@"Resources\certificate.pfx", "Password123")
```

Locally this works fine however when I publish it to azure app service the server logs shows

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(Byte[] rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)at IdentityServerAspNetIdentity.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in ...
```

If I modify the password and try to run it locally I get the same error. It works fine until it is published. I'm not quite sure what could be causing it

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct` error:

You can try as suggested by [bartonjs (Jeremy Barton) · GitHub](https://github.com/bartonjs) :

Try setting the app config setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1` (from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27358#issuecomment-509961051). Or change `cert = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes, (string)null);`  to `cert = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);`

References: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30658#issuecomment-523946164 , https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25143 and [Loading X509 Certificate: Error in Azure, can't reproduce locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644446/loading-x509-certificate-error-in-azure-cant-reproduce-locally)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue with Azure so instead of loading the certificate from the file system, we installed and loaded the certificate directly from Azure using the thumbprint as suggested in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code). Make sure to configure the environment variable "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" with the same thumbprint value that is generated while installing the certificate.

```
 using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                            // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                                            thumbPrint,
                                            false);
                // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
                X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault();

                if (cert is null)
                    throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint {thumbPrint} was not found");

                return ((IIbanityServiceMutualTlsBuilder)this).AddClientCertificate(cert);

            }
```